# trying to build rpm, receive ld error

Tags: makefile, centos, rpm, squid

I'm trying to install squid from source.
I issue the command make but it gets this error at the end:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [basic_ncsa_auth] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/squid-3.4.6/helpers/basic_auth/NCSA'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/squid-3.4.6/helpers/basic_auth'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/squid-3.4.6/helpers'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the OpenSSL development toolkit installed.

```
yum install openssl
```

Comment: yum install openssl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirrors.coreix.net
 * remi: mirror.1000mbps.com
 * updates: mirrors.coreix.net
Setting up Install Process
Package openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: yum install openssl-devel

Comment: Don't forget to add <code>BuildRequires: openssl-devel</code> (with a version, if it matters...)